# How to center this heading above paragraph?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I am working on a website where each page will have a heading, a small paragraph, and an image. I need to center the heading directly above the paragraph, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this for headings of different lengths. What works for a short heading won't work for a longer one.

I've been experimenting with different properties like position: absolute, etc., but I haven't found anything that gives me the result I need. Can anyone help?

```css
p {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 2;
  color: black;
}

img {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 39%;
  top: 10%;
  border: 10px solid white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2356045/pexels-photo-2356045.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but it's really simple. Try adding spaces before the word "heading".

Comment: @FuzzySquid No, that won't work

Comment: just u want to have heading centered above the paragraph i'm right ?@Leia_Organa

Comment: Oh. Is it because HTML removes whitespaces?

Comment: you have a closing `</div>` tag in your html but no opening tag

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a div at the bottom, do you have a beginning div above the H1 tag?

1 way is to do this:

```
 h1{
    text-align:center;
 }
```

or give that H1 tag a class name so that you will affect only those with that class name

```
.page-title{
    text-align:center;
}    

<h1 class="page-title">
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a code pen. So what I did was remove `position: absolute;` because position gets tricky, instead I added `div` around both the content and the image and added `display: inline-block;` to the `div`. Lastly I changed `text-align: left;` to `text-align: center;` on the `h1` Code Pen can be found here: https://codepen.io/the_legitTDM/pen/WVOvjp

Answer (score 0):

Are u expecting like this:

```css
div {
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
left: 5%;
color: black;
}
p{
background-color: green;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 15px;
height: auto;    
}

img {
height: 250px;
margin: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 39%;
top: 12%;
border: 10px solid white;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2356045/pexels-photo-2356045.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
```